# How to implement snap to center in SpriteKit?

Tags: sprite-kit

Basically, I have many `SKNodes` in my `SKScene`. I can't use `SKAction` because I want the physics engine to handle collisions for me so my only option left is to use use physics. How would I go about this? Ex: when a node is tapped, it should snap to the center of the screen
while also having other nodes bounce off during collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've figured it out. All I had to do was calculate the vector from my current node position to the center and apply a magnified velocity to my node towards that direction. In the `update` method of my `SKScene`, I constantly check to see if I'm within a certain radius of the center and if I am, I just set the velocity of my node to 0. That stops it at the center. The beauty of this too is that for my other nodes that aren't centered, if I drag them into the center node and move the center node elsewhere, after the drag finishes, the center node snaps back.

You can check out my solution here: https://github.com/ThasianX/ElegantColorPalette